# How to make divs names always be 1,2,3 jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is that when i append 2 divs white jQuery, there names are:
This is div 1
This is div 2

But when i remove the first div (This is div 1)

and append another div
it adds one more div whit name (This is div 2):
This is div 2
This is div 2

The reason is because the name of the div counts the total amout of divs... Is there any other way to number all divs so they will always be like this:
This is div 1
This is div 2
This is div 3

Even if i the divs are:
This is div 1
This is div 6
This is div 12

I want them always to be 1,2,3

jQuery code:

```
$('#add_item').click(function() {
    //div count
    var countDivs = $("div").length;

    //append content
    var removeBtn = ('<a class="removeBtn">x</a>')
    var h2 = ('<h2>This is div '+countDivs+'</h2>')
    var appendContent = ('<div>'+h2+removeBtn+'</div>') 
    $('#accordion').append(appendContent);
});

//remove button
$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
    $(this).parent('div').andSelf().remove();
    return false;
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1v6anhv3/)

Comment: why you want name to be 1,2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to edit contents of the divs each time a div is removed.

Let's say you have an element  and you want to add divs to it.

You will add like you are right now and when you remove you edit all other divs.

The code would be something like this

```
$('#add_item').click(function() {
  var countDivs = $("div").length;
  var removeBtn = ('<a class="removeBtn">x</a>')
  var h2 = ('<h2>This is div '+countDivs+'</h2>')
  var appendContent = ('<div class="appDiv">'+h2+removeBtn+'</div>') 
  $('#accordion').append(appendContent);
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').andSelf().remove();
  $('.appDiv').each(function(index,el){
    $(el).find('h2').text('This is div '+(index+1));
  });
  return false;
});
```

here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1v6anhv3/3/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: what is the (index,el) stands for?

Comment: @Alfonso : `$('.appDiv')` gives you all elements in an array sequentially. We use [jQuery's each function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to cycle through all the elements one by one. for the `each` function you pass in a callback which gets `index` i.e. the index of the element being cycled and `el` which is the element in question.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function to renaming the divs and call it after append/remove.

```
function reArrange() {
  $("#accordion > div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).find("h2").text("This is div" + (i + 1))
  });

}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1v6anhv3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

When an item is removed, change the title of all the elements after it.

```js
$('#add_item').click(function() {
  var countDivs = $("#accordion div").length + 1;
  var removeBtn = ('<a class="removeBtn">x</a>')
  var h2 = ('<h2>This is div <span>' + countDivs + '</span></h2>')
  var appendContent = ('<div>' + h2 + removeBtn + '</div>')
  $('#accordion').append(appendContent);
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
  var $div = $(this).parent();
  $div.nextAll('div').find('span').html(function(i, html) {
    return --html
  });
  $div.remove();
  return false;
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
#accordion {
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
#add_item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.removeBtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2px 10px 5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: verdana;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
</div>
<a id="add_item">+</a>
```

Comment: Hi if possible answer this.. i will delete this comment in 5 min http://stackoverflow.com/q/37475968/5967286

Answer (score 1):

you should use a global variable like "count":

```js
var count=1;



$('#add_item').click(function() {
    //div count
  //var countDivs = $("div").length;
  var countDivs =count;

    //append content
  var removeBtn = ('<a class="removeBtn">x</a>')
  var h2 = ('<h2>This is div '+countDivs+'</h2>')
  var appendContent = ('<div>'+h2+removeBtn+'</div>') 
  $('#accordion').append(appendContent);
  count++;
});

//remove button
$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').andSelf().remove();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest update would be to trigger a recount (or other named-event) and, upon addition or removal of an element – by clicking either the `#add_item` or `.removeBtn` – call that function using the `on()` method to listen for that event.

In the below code we bind the event-listener to the `#accordion` element, as the closest ancestor present in the DOM on page load:

```
$('#add_item').click(function() {
  var removeBtn = ('<a class="removeBtn">x</a>');
  var h2 = ('<h2></h2>');
  var appendContent = ('<div>'+h2+removeBtn+'</div>');
  $('#accordion').append(appendContent).trigger('recount');
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').andSelf().remove();

  // triggering the 'recount' event from the
  // #accordion:
  $('#accordion').trigger('recount');
  return false;
});

// listening for the 'recount' event:
$('#accordion').on('recount', function(){

  // looking within the #accordion for
  // the <h2> elements (which contain the
  // text to update), and using the text()
  // method's anonymous function along with
  // its i argument (the index of the current
  // <h2> in the collection):
  $(this).find('h2').text(function(i){

    // returning the text string concatenated
    // with the index plus 1 (to get a 1-based
    // count, rather than JavaScript's 0-based):
    return 'This is div ' + (i + 1);
  });
});
```

```js
$('#add_item').click(function() {
  var removeBtn = ('<a class="removeBtn">x</a>');
  var h2 = ('<h2></h2>');
  var appendContent = ('<div>' + h2 + removeBtn + '</div>');
  $('#accordion').append(appendContent).trigger('recount');
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeBtn', function() {
  $(this).parent('div').andSelf().remove();
  $('#accordion').trigger('recount');
  return false;
});

$('#accordion').on('recount', function() {
  $(this).find('h2').text(function(i) {
    return 'This is div ' + (i + 1);
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
#accordion {
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
}
#add_item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.removeBtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 2px 10px 5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  font-family: verdana;
  border-radius: 100%;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
</div>
<a id="add_item">+</a>
```

References:

- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).